# Apache zeppelin - How to Schedule Notebooks sequentially?

Tags: apache-zeppelin, hdp

I am new to Apache zeppelin. Can someone help me how do we create a workflow of zeppelin notebooks.

Comment: I'm not sure you can. You would use Oozie for creating a workflow DAG.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that.